# How to change the site setting menu text color from black to white

Tags: 2013, master-page, page-layout, css

How I can modify the CSS to change the site setting menu text color from black to white. I am unable to locate the id for these items using IE developer tool. Can anyone advice ?
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your css

```
.ms-siteactions-root a {
   color: #the_color_you_want !important;
}
```

With firebug these changes are easy to achieve. Why don't you give a try?